# Issue opening sqlite database connection in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-connection

In some cases when I try to open my sqlite database with the follownig code:

```
  dbManager.open();
```

where the method is shown below:

```
  SQLiteDatabase mDb;
  DbHelper mDbHelper;

   public void open(){  
        mDb=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   }
```

I obtain this error:

```
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/act.myactivity/databases/seasonDb' 
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1980)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:977)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:753)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at host.database.DB_DatabaseManager.open(DB_DatabaseManager.java:136)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at host.framework.ServicePromemoria.checkUnSyncInsert(ServicePromemoria.java:265)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at host.framework.ServicePromemoria$1.run(ServicePromemoria.java:59)
11-08 12:39:25.760: E/SQLiteDatabase(5603):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

I think this is related to the attempt to open database that has not been closed.

p.s.: the method for closing database connection is :

```
 public void close(){
        mDb.close();
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the core of `checkUnSyncInsert()`:

```
  dbManager.open(); //here error occurs
    String getUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM user";
    Cursor c = dbManager.RawQuery(getUserQuery, null);

    if(c.getCount() != 0)
    {
        try{
            c.moveToFirst();
            usr = c.getString(0).toString();
            pwd = c.getString(1).toString();
            Log.i("USERNAME: "+pwd,"PASSWORD: "+pwd);
            c.close();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            c.close();
        }
    }
    else

    dbManager.close();
```

The error occurs at first line (`dbManager.open()`)

Comment: Where did you call close() ?

did you call it onDestroy() ?

Comment: Show the source of `checkUnSyncInsert`.

Comment: I want just know if an error occurs if I don't close the db and I try to open it. I edit my question with checkUnSyncInsert

Answer (score 0):

you only close if there is nothing returned. If this piece of code runs several times, then the error is understandable, because the second time the close is missing while opening

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are closing the database before trying to open it again.
You can even open and close the database inside your method as :

```
public void addGroupContact(String groupId, String contactId) {

        Log.d("Database : ", "*****************Ädd Group Contact******************");
        mDbHelper = new NewDatabaseHelper();
        mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NewDatabaseHelper.KEY_GROUP_F_ID, groupId); // Group Id
        values.put(NewDatabaseHelper.KEY_CONTACT_ID, contactId); // contact id
        // Inserting Row
        mDatabase.insert(NewDatabaseHelper.TABLE_GROUPS_CONTACTS, null, values);
        mDatabase.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to be sure that database is closed on Destroy and Pause